# PHP setting up security questions

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have been looking around for a while using google, and haven't been able to find an answer to this question.

I am trying to set up a site that has the user setup security questions and answers for their account upon registration (This part I can manage without issue).  What I can't figure out how to do is have the site recognize the user's computer when they go to log in so they don't have to answer the questions each time they log in.

I can't do it via IP address as some providers will change the public IP of a user every so often (my provider changes my public IP every hour, it seems).

Is there a way to do it via MAC Address or some unique identifier for their specific machine or device.  That way if "Joe" creates an account, but his roommate "Bob" tries to get into his account from a different computer or device in the same house/apartment it will ask the questions to "Bob", but not to "Joe" since it recognizes his device(s)?

Hoping I am making what I am trying to do clear.

Comment: upon login, you create a random key, which you then store in the users cookies. Once the user checks back to your site, you can lookup for the key and verify the user is authenticated.

Comment: Normally you need to store authorization cookie into user's browser upon successful authentication and then check if this cookie is available. Make sure that cookie is marked as "http only"

Comment: so to make sure I am understanding this correctly, create a cookie marked "http only" upon registration / successful registration, and put a generated random key in that cookie for the server to check for when logging in to authenticate the user, correct?

Comment: Yes. Upon Registration / Login -> create random key -> store key in a seperate mysql table on server + in clients' cookies. When user tries to access pages which need authentication, you simply check if the user has that cookie, then lookup in the mysql table if the key is valid.

Comment: Use sessions: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Comment: thanks for the information, and help!

Comment: I know it took you a lot of effort, and you saw security questions in many "major" sites, but it's a really bad an anoying security policy.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to set up a site that has the user setup security questions and answers for their account upon registration (This part I can manage without issue).

This is [a bad design](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/09/untangling-forget-me-knot-secure-account-recovery-made-simple), and leads to situations like [the time Governor Sarah Palin's email was hacked via password reset questions](https://www.wired.com/2008/09/palin-e-mail-ha/).

> Is there a way to do it via MAC Address or some unique identifier for their specific machine or device.

No, your local MAC address isn't transmitted to remote servers. Any other such hardware identifier is easily spoofed.

> What I can't figure out how to do is have the site recognize the user's computer when they go to log in so they don't have to answer the questions each time they log in.

In that case, what you want is a slight variant of [long-term authentication cookies](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2.1) that serves to partially authenticate the user so they don't need to go through extra security measures.

Normally the design I linked to is for "remember me on this computer" checkboxes that cause websites to automatically log users in even when they close their browser. However, you can repurpose it to solve this sort of problem.

However, I strongly advise against bothering with security questions. Have you considered two-factor authentication (FIDO U2F or TOTP; never SMS) as your extra security layer instead of easily-defeated security questions?